# SQL: Как получить всех потомков для определенного родителя?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется такая таблица:

USERS

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | null |
| 2 | Bob | 1 |
| 3 | Mark | 1 |
| 4 | Sean | 2 |
| 5 | Leon | 3 |
| 6 | Fred | 4 |
| 7 | Irma | 5 |
| 8 | Lisa | 5 |

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне сделать выборку пользователя Mark и всех его потомков, включая потомков его потомков, чтобы в результате мне вернулся список пользователей с идентификаторами: 3, 5, 7, 8?

Comment: Есть разные способы хранения иерархий в БД: [Иерархические структуры и деревья в SQL](https://www.osp.ru/pcworld/2007/03/4199032), [Способы хранения деревьев в реляционных базах данных](https://bitworks.software/2017-10-20-storing-trees-in-rdbms.html). Вы используете Список смежности (Adjacency List). В статьях по ссылкам приведены примеры базовых запросов.

Comment: Оставьте **ОДНУ** СУБД, удалите лишний тег. Укажите точную версию.

Comment: субд postgresql

Comment: ещё стоит вместо картинки приводить операторы создания и наполнения таблицы данными

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with recursive hierarchy(id, name, parent_id) as (
  select * from users where id=3 -- Mark
  union all
  select users.* from users,hierarchy where users.parent_id = hierarchy.id 
)
select * from hierarchy
```